# Use RDF4J API to access GraphDB secured wih OIDC

Tags: graphdb, rdf4j

When GraphDB access is secured with OpenID connect (configuration option `openid`) using an OAuth user database (`oauth`), is it still possible to access the GraphDB instance in Java using the RDF4J API?

As per the [documentation](https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.3/access-control.html#what-s-in-this-document), it seems that this is not possible, because AFAIK RDF4J API uses basic authentication to connect to the repository and openid + basic is not a valid authentication method combination in GraphDB.